# Kotlin - how to unit test function with nested suspend function

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, suspend

I'm wrapper a function into another one, making the function as a parameter to the other, but **I'm having a hard time to modify the existing unit test.**

The wrapper function is called withLock(), which do something before and after the real function. Pasting my code below:

- Original standalone function `V1` and its unit test

```
suspend fun V1 : RandomType (
    // Step A
    // Step B
    // Step C
    return RandomType
)

@Test
fun `test V1` (
    // stubStepA
    // stubStepB
    // stubStepC

    call V1()

    // verify results 
)
```

- The withLock() function and how I wrap it in `V2`

```
suspend fun <T : Any> withLock(
    function: suspend () -> T
): T {
    acquireLock()
    val res = function()
    releaseLock()
    return res
}

suspend fun V2 : RandomType (
    return withLock() {
        // Step A
        // Step B
        // Step C
    }
)
```

**Want to know how am I supposed to modify the unit test to be able to test withLock()**

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way to test it, of course acquireLock/releaseLock aren't checked directly but if check the function was executed inside withLock:

```
class LockTest {

    suspend fun whatever() : String = "whatever"

    suspend fun V2(): String {
        return withLock(::whatever)
    }
}

@Test
fun `test`() = runBlockingTest {

    val lockTest = spyK(LockTest())
    lockTest.V2()
    coVerify { lockTest.whatever() }
}
```

Comment: Hi lgor, thanks for the answer. However, besides verifying `whatever()` is being executed, I also need to verify a few logics of `whatever()`.

Plus, I think I might need to mock `withLock()` as I'm getting error messages saying "io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: XXX.withLock()"